# my code excutes from last to first and how to execute on single button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

In below code i'm trying to get the values of individual inputs and on one single click display results as images. the code is working for individual input and from last to first I have only enabled fields which are DC Inputs, DC Outputs, Analog In and Analog Out. how can i make it to display images on single click after all the numbers enterd

DC Input: 16
DC Output: 16
Analog In: 8
Analog Out: 4

```js
function toggleVisibility(id) {
   var el = document.getElementById(id);
    
   if (el.style.display=="block") { 
          el.style.display="none";
     }
     else {
          el.style.display="block";
     }
 }

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#aibox").keyup(function(event) {   // bind function called when key is released
   $(".aibox").html("<input type=\"text\" id=\"aic\" placeholder=\"4-20mA\" size=\"10\"><br><input type=\"text\" id=\"aiv\" placeholder=\"0-10V\" size=\"10\">");
  });
  $("button").click(function() {  // click method to call keydown() function
    $("#aibox").keyup();
  });
 
 
 $("#aobox").keyup(function(event) {   // bind function called when key is released
   $(".aobox").html("<input type=\"text\" id=\"aoc\" placeholder=\"4-20mA\" size=\"10\"><br><input type=\"text\" id=\"aov\" placeholder=\"0-10V\" size=\"10\"> ");
  });
  $("button").click(function() {  // click method to call keydown() function
    $("#aobox").keyup();
  });
 
 });
  


function checkName() {
 
    var text;

 var di = document.getElementById("dibox").value;
 if (di >= 16)  {
        text = "Use Digital Input Module";
  document.getElementById('EZLGX-IO-16DCI').style.display='block'
                return false;
  
 } 
 
 var doo = document.getElementById("dobox").value;
 if (doo >= 16)  {
        text = "Use Digital Output Module";
  document.getElementById('EZLGX-IO-16DCOP').style.display='block'
                return false;
  
 }
  
 var ainc = document.getElementById("aic").value;
   var ainv = document.getElementById("aiv").value;
    var aonc = document.getElementById("aoc").value;
   var aonv = document.getElementById("aov").value;
    //first If
 if ((ainc && aonc <= 2) || (ainv && aonv <= 2)) {
        text = "Use Two Combo Module";
  document.getElementById('EZLGX-IO-4ACI4ACO').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('EZLGX-IO-8ACI').style.display='block';
                return false;
        
 // seconf if|| (ainv && aonv >= 3))
    } else if (ainc && aonc >= 3)  {
        text = "Use Analog Input Current Module";
  document.getElementById('EZLGX-IO-8ANI4ANOC').style.display='block';
                return false; 
  
  } else if (ainv && aonv >= 3)  {
        text = "Use Analog Input Voltage Module";
  document.getElementById('EZLGX-IO-8ANI4ANOV').style.display='block';
                return false;

    // last if
    } else {
        text = "Waaay off..";
    }
 
 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table width="815" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"><strong>CPU</strong></td>
      <td><label for="EZLGX-CPU-1UE">EZLGX-CPU-1UE</label> <input type="checkbox" name="finallevelusers[]" onChange="toggleVisibility('EZLGX-CPU-1UE');"/> </td>
      <td colspan="3">CPU 500K words ladder memory, USB, Micro SD, Ethernet and 1 RS232/422/48 ports.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="EZLGX-CPU-2UE">EZLGX-CPU-2UE</label><input type="checkbox" name="finallevelusers[]" onChange="toggleVisibility('EZLGX-CPU-2UE');"/> </td>
      <td colspan="3">CPU 500K words ladder memory, USB, Micro SD, Ethernet and 2 RS232/422/48 ports.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="20%"><strong>DC Inputs</strong></td>
      <td width="20%"><strong>DC Outputs</strong></td>
      <td width="20%"><strong>AC Inputs</strong></td>
      <td width="20%"><strong>AC Outputs</strong></td>
      <td width="20%"><strong>High Speed Counter</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" style="font-size:11px"><input type="text" id="dibox" size="10" onkeyup="sum();"/>
        <!--<div class="dibox"></div>--></td>
      <td valign="top" style="font-size:11px"><input type="text" id="dobox" size="10" onkeyup="sum();"/>
        <!--<div class="dobox"></div>--></td>
      <td valign="top" style="font-size:11px"><input type="text" id="acibox" size="10" onkeyup="sum();"/>
        <div class="acibox"></div></td>
      <td valign="top" style="font-size:11px"><input type="text" id="acobox" size="10" onkeyup="sum();"/>
        <div class="acobox"></div></td>
      <td valign="top" style="font-size:11px"><input type="text" id="hscbox" size="10" onkeyup="sum();"/><div class="hscbox"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Anaog Input</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Analog Output</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Temperature Input</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Relay Output</strong></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" style="font-size:11px"><input type="text" id="aibox" size="10" onkeyup="sum();"/>
        <div class="aibox"></div></td>
      <td valign="top" style="font-size:11px"><input type="text" id="aobox" size="10" onkeyup="sum();"/>
        <div class="aobox"></div></td>
      <td valign="top" style="font-size:11px"><input type="text" id="tibox" size="10" onkeyup="sum();"/>
        <div class="tibox"></div></td>
      <td valign="top" style="font-size:11px"><input type="text" id="ribox" size="10" onkeyup="sum();"/>
        <div class="ribox"></div></td>
      <td valign="top" style="font-size:11px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
      <div class="box" style=" overflow: auto; height: 275px;"><hr /><img id="EZLGX-CPU-1UE" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-CPU-1UE.png"  style="display: none; float: left"/><img id="EZLGX-CPU-2UE" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-CPU-2UE.png"  style="display: none; float: left"/><img id="EZLGX-IO-16DCI" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-16DCI.png"  style="display: none; float: left"/><img id="EZLGX-IO-8ACI" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-8ACI.png"  style="display: none; float: left"/><img id="EZLGX-IO-4ACI4ACO" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-4ACI4ACO.png"  style="display: none; float: left"/><img id="EZLGX-IO-16DCOP" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-16DCOP.png"  style="display: none; float: left"/><img id="EZLGX-IO-16DCON" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-16DCON.png"  style="display: none; float: left"/><img id="EZLGX-IO-4DCOP4RLO" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-4DCOP4RLO.png"  style="display: none; float: left"/>
      <img id="EZLGX-IO-8RLO" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-8RLO.png"  style="display: none; float: left"/>
      <img id="EZLGX-IO-8ACO" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-8ACO.png"  style="display: none; float: left"/>
      <img id="EZLGX-IO-8ANI4ANOV" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-8ANI4ANOV.png"  style="display: none; float: left"/>
      <img id="EZLGX-IO-8ANI4ANOC" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-8ANI4ANOC.png"  style="display: none; float: left"/>
      <img id="EZLGX-IO-4THIE" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-4THIE.png"  style="display: none; float: left"/>
      <img id="EZLGX-IO-4RTD" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-4RTD.png"  style="display: none; float: left"/>
      <img id="EZLGX-IO-HSCNT" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-HSCNT.png"  style="display: none; float: left"/>
      
      </div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 
<!--Analog In<input type="text" id="aic" placeholder="4-20mA" ><br><input type="text" id="aiv" placeholder="0-10V" ><br>
<br>
Analog Out<input type="text" id="aoc" placeholder="4-20mA" ><br><input type="text" id="aov" placeholder="0-10V" ><br><br>-->
<button id="plc" onclick="checkName()">Check Name</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I don't why its giving error here...It works fine when i have it all in one page. Anyways any suggestion on how to do this will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simplify**

By simplifying things we can see a few problems.

- The form values should be converted to a number with `parseInt`. The value property gives them to you as strings so `"16" >= 16` will work because JavaScript coerces the value but you should check that the user entered a valid number and not a letter.
- The ids specified in the script don't match up with ids in the HTML. I made a guess but it's hard to tell if `aic` means AC Input or Analog Input.
- Every `if` statement returns false so the `demo` text never gets populated.

Fixing some of these problems might bet you back on the right track. Good luck!

```js
function checkName() {
  var text = 'Waaay off..';

  var di = parseInt(document.getElementById('dibox').value);
  var doo = parseInt(document.getElementById('dobox').value);
  var ainc = parseInt(document.getElementById('acibox').value);
  var ainv = parseInt(document.getElementById('aibox').value);
  var aonc = parseInt(document.getElementById('acobox').value);
  var aonv = parseInt(document.getElementById('aobox').value);

  if (di >= 16) {
    text = 'Use Digital Input Module';
    document.getElementById('EZLGX-IO-16DCI').style.display = 'block';
  } else if (doo >= 16) {
    text = 'Use Digital Output Module';
    document.getElementById('EZLGX-IO-16DCOP').style.display = 'block';
  } else if ((ainc && aonc <= 2) || (ainv && aonv <= 2)) {
    text = 'Use Two Combo Module';
    document.getElementById('EZLGX-IO-4ACI4ACO').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('EZLGX-IO-8ACI').style.display = 'block';
  } else if (ainc && aonc >= 3) {
    text = 'Use Analog Input Current Module';
    document.getElementById('EZLGX-IO-8ANI4ANOC').style.display = 'block';
  } else if (ainv && aonv >= 3) {
    text = 'Use Analog Input Voltage Module';
    document.getElementById('EZLGX-IO-8ANI4ANOV').style.display = 'block';
  }

  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<label for="dibox">DC Inputs: </label><input type="text" id="dibox" size="10"><br>
<label for="dobox">DC Outputs: </label><input type="text" id="dobox" size="10"><br>
<label for="acibox">AC Inputs: </label><input type="text" id="acibox" size="10"><br>
<label for="acobox">AC Outputs: </label><input type="text" id="acobox" size="10"><br>
<label for="hscbox">High Speed Counter: </label><input type="text" id="hscbox" size="10"><br>
<label for="aibox">Anaog Input: </label><input type="text" id="aibox" size="10"><br>
<label for="aobox">Analog Output: </label><input type="text" id="aobox" size="10"><br>
<label for="tibox">Temperature Input: </label><input type="text" id="tibox" size="10"><br>
<label for="ribox">Relay Output: </label><input type="text" id="ribox" size="10"><br>

<img id="EZLGX-CPU-1UE" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-CPU-1UE.png" style="display: none;">
<img id="EZLGX-CPU-2UE" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-CPU-2UE.png" style="display: none;">
<img id="EZLGX-IO-16DCI" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-16DCI.png" style="display: none;">
<img id="EZLGX-IO-8ACI" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-8ACI.png" style="display: none;">
<img id="EZLGX-IO-4ACI4ACO" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-4ACI4ACO.png" style="display: none;">
<img id="EZLGX-IO-16DCOP" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-16DCOP.png" style="display: none;">
<img id="EZLGX-IO-16DCON" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-16DCON.png" style="display: none;">
<img id="EZLGX-IO-4DCOP4RLO" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-4DCOP4RLO.png" style="display: none;">
<img id="EZLGX-IO-8RLO" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-8RLO.png" style="display: none;">
<img id="EZLGX-IO-8ACO" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-8ACO.png" style="display: none;">
<img id="EZLGX-IO-8ANI4ANOV" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-8ANI4ANOV.png" style="display: none;">
<img id="EZLGX-IO-8ANI4ANOC" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-8ANI4ANOC.png" style="display: none;">
<img id="EZLGX-IO-4THIE" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-4THIE.png" style="display: none;">
<img id="EZLGX-IO-4RTD" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-4RTD.png" style="display: none;">
<img id="EZLGX-IO-HSCNT" src="http://www.ezautomation.net/ioconfig/img/EZLGX-IO-HSCNT.png" style="display: none;">

<br><button onclick="checkName()">Check Name</button>
<br>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks Will for your comments. I'll edit to see the result.

Comment: Also, I need each inputs to show a respective image depending on the value of the input. If suppose for DC Input it's 16 - show 1 img, 32 - show 2 img. Can you please help me with a example of how to do that!! My apologies if i'm asking too much!